# Как распечатать каждый HTML-блок на отдельном листе?

Tags: html, css

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Как распечатать каждый `<div>` на отдельном листе при условии, что размеры точно не известны?

---

Если быть точнее, то в каждом `<div>` находится таблица (`<table>`) календарного месяца; в такой таблице может быть либо 5, либо 6, либо 7 строк, в зависимости от даты; поэтому размеры колеблются.

Comment: page-break-after

Comment: @splash58, спасибо, я как раз сам нашёл у наших англоязычных товарищей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как подсказал [splash58](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507045/201026#comment611188_507045) и как я нашёл ответ на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14686883/4223982), можно использовать CSS-свойство [`page-break-after`](https://webref.ru/css/page-break-after):

```
@media print {
  div {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

Ну и конечно, есть и другие аналогичные свойства, если нужно:

- [`page-break-before`](https://webref.ru/css/page-break-before);
- [`page-break-inside`](https://webref.ru/css/page-break-inside).